# How to pass parameters between two javascript file using require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I 'm trying to pass parameters using require.js, either objects, arrays, number or string, but i have a problem, to receive the parameter shows me ***undefined***.

object

```
estudiante: Object
ApelEstu: "Vides"
CeduEstu: "11223344"
FacuEstu: "Tecno e Ing"
Login_Usuario: "dfvides"
NombEstu: "Diego"
ProgEstu: "Sistemas"
RolEstu: 1
Semestre: 10
```

index

```
require(['configuracion'], function (){

           require(['login']);

        });
```

config(require.js)

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'js',
paths: {        

    jquery: ['librerias/jquery-1.11.2.min',            
              'librearias/jquery-2.1.3.min'],

    login: 'proyecto/login',     
    database: 'proyecto/db'

}


});
```

login.js(data contain object)

```
console.log(data);
        var estu = data.estudiante;
        //console.log(estu);

        base.iniciarbase();
        base.guardar(estu);
```

db.js(contain module)

```
define(function (){

   var database = {

       crear: function(){} --> done,
       tablas: function(){} --> done,
       insertarperfil: function(){} --fail
                };
    });

    return {

      iniciarbase: function (){
          return database.tablas();
      },

      guardar: function (){
          return database.insertarperfil();
      }

  };
    });
```

function insert parameters

```
insertarperfil: function (Estudiante){

        console.log(Estudiante);
        var db, SqlGuardar, SqlDelete, SqlBuscar, mostrar;

        db = database.crear();
        SqlBuscar = 'SELECT * FROM Estudiante';
        SqlGuardar = 'INSERT INTO Estudiante(cedula, nombre, apellido, rol, facultad, programa, semestre) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';                                              
        SqlDelete = 'DELETE FROM Estudiante';

        db.transaction(function (tx) {

        tx.executeSql(SqlBuscar, [], function (tx, results){

            mostrar = results.rows.length;

            if (mostrar === 0){                      

                tx.executeSql(SqlGuardar, [Estudiante.CeduEstu, Estudiante.NombEstu, Estudiante.ApelEstu, Estudiante.RolEstu, 
                                           Estudiante.FacuEstu, Estudiante.ProgEstu, Estudiante.Semestre]); 




            }else{

                tx.executeSql(SqlDelete);

                tx.executeSql(SqlGuardar, [Estudiante.CeduEstu, Estudiante.NombEstu, Estudiante.ApelEstu, Estudiante.RolEstu, 
                                           Estudiante.FacuEstu, Estudiante.ProgEstu, Estudiante.Semestre]);



            }

        });

    });

    }
```

function return saludo

```
saludoestu: function (){

        var db, saludo, SqlConsulta;

        db = database.crear();
        //id = metodosestu.setCedulaEstu();
        SqlConsulta = 'SELECT nombre, apellido FROM Estudiante';

        db.transaction(function (tx) {

            tx.executeSql(SqlConsulta, [], function (tx, results){

                var numero = results.rows.length;
                //var saludo = new Object();

                for (var i=0;i<numero;i++){

                    saludo = {
                         nombre: results.rows.item(i).nombre,
                         apellido: results.rows.item(i).apellido
                    };
                    //console.log(saludo);                    
                }
                return (saludo);

            });

        });

    }

     return {


      saludar: function (){
          return database.saludoestu();
      }

  };
```

call function in the login

```
var n =  base.saludar(saludo);
            console.log(n);
```

above him toward using prototype but I also throws the same error only in new projects, old prototype works projects

Comment: where and what is your `data.estudiante`?

Comment: is an object contain that  estudiante: Object
ApelEstu: "Vides"
CeduEstu: "11223344"
FacuEstu: "Tecno e Ing"
Login_Usuario: "dfvides"
NombEstu: "Diego"
ProgEstu: "Sistemas"
RolEstu: 1
Semestre: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import code from another module, include `require` in your define function:

```
define(function(require) { // <=== use require
   var db = require('pathToFile/db'); // <=== get file

   var iniciarbase= db.iniciarbase; // <=== call function from another module
   console.log(iniciarbase);

   var guardar= db.guardar;
   console.log(guardar);
});
```

Edit: Use return in a module like an api, to expose only the functions you want other modules to use:

```
define(function (){

   var database = {

       crear          : function(){}, // include comma
       tablas         : function(){}, // include comma
       insertarperfil : function(){} // no comma

    });

    return {

      iniciarbase : database.tablas, // don't use ()
      guardar     : database.insertarperfil

  };
});
```

Edit 2:

login.js

```
define(function(require) { // <=== use require
   var db = require('./database'); // <=== get file

    var estu = {
        'ApelEstu': "Vides",
        'CeduEstu': "11223344",
        'FacuEstu': "Tecno e Ing",
        'Login_Usuario': "dfvides",
        'NombEstu': "Diego",
        'ProgEstu': "Sistemas",
        'RolEstu': 1,
        'Semestre': 10
    };

    db.iniciarbase(); 
    db.guardar(estu); // <=== pass object to db module
});
```

db.js

```
define(function (){

   var database = {

       crear: function(){},
       tablas: function(){},
       insertarperfil: function(estu){ // <=== pass estu
          // do stuff here with estu
       } 
    });

    return {

      iniciarbase: function (){
          return database.tablas();
      },

      guardar: function (estu){ // <=== FORGOT TO ADD estu HERE
          return database.insertarperfil(estu); 
      }

  };
    });
```

Comment: se that

require(['jquery', 'database'], function (_,base){

  console.log(data);
            var estu = data.estudiante;
            //console.log(estu);
            
            base.iniciarbase();
            base.guardar(estu);

});

but show this error


undefined
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CeduEstu' of undefined(anonymous function) @ db.js:70

Comment: sorry, but u can put the last code where u show the function return

Comment: but, i need send the object data.estudiante for insert in the web database, but when the parameter are in the module, show undefined, now have this error

$ is not defined

Comment: you can pass anything into your db module, e.g. `db.iniciarbase(myObject);` Can you post the code/module for your estudiante object in your original question...

Comment: i post the code in the question, if u want i pass all code using pastebin

Comment: i just need to know how you're trying to pass your object into the db module.

Comment: insertarperfil: function (Estudiante) --> db.js

 base.guardar(estu); --> login.js

Comment: I don't understand this: `SELECT * FROM Estudiante`, are you trying to pass an object into your sql?

Comment: no, this Estudiante into the query is the table name, the other Estudiante is here
tx.executeSql(SqlGuardar, [Estudiante.CeduEstu,...]

Comment: now show that
Uncaught ReferenceError: estu is not defined
but i declare var estu; , show that
undefined

Comment: oops, i forgot to add estu to the guardar function in db : `guardar: function (estu){` see edit #2

Comment: men, i have a problem, now can't return a parameter, i edit the original post, u can check??

Comment: You need to use a callback if doing a database transaction.

Comment: i create new module with require. js after call antwhere work, thx, i see the callback thing, thx